# How to add custom template in Bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am very new in bigcommerce and I have to display latest product in page for that I want to create custom template in bigcommerce. I am using Chelsea-edited 1.10.0 Stencil theme of bigcommerce.

Anyone know how to create template in bigcommerce?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/authoring-custom-templates

Comment: Thanks for the answer